# how to get Snowflake 32bit ODBC driver in Linux

Tags: linux, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, 32-bit

Does anyone know how to get Snowflake 32bit ODBC driver in Linux? I install ODBC driver in Linux using snowflake-odbc-2.21.3.x86_64.rpm, but can only find one libSnowflake.so file which is 64bit. But I see Snowflake ODBC driver support both 32bit and 64bit application in website(https://www.cdata.com/drivers/snowflake/odbc/?msclkid=70ffa5bf66d21688fb3dc50fdc277093&utm_source=bing&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=CData%20-%20Search%20-%20Source%20-%20Snowflake&utm_term=snowflake%20ODBC%20Driver&utm_content=ODBC%20Driver%20-%20Snowflake).
How can I connect Snowflake with 32bit ODBC driver in Linux?

Comment: https://sfc-repo.snowflakecomputing.com/odbc/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Snowflake does not provide a 32bit Linux version for ODBC driver, it is available only for Windows OS.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Do you know if 32bit application can connect to Snowflake with ODBC driver in Linux or not?